# How to fix python manage.py giving no response

Tags: python, django

When I run the command **python manage.py runserver**

[image: This is what I get]

I have installed python 3.9.0 and django 3.2.10

Comment: can you explain bit more about how this issue arised. Did you make any changes to manage.py accidently. Or anything.

Comment: Can you give us the rezult of the command `pip freeze` ? And the files name from the directory that you are?

Comment: Connect with me on skype, i will fix that - live:mracatech

Comment: It got fixed microsoft store also got python 3.9 and that was the problem. So by installing Python from MS and then unistalled it and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also resolve this without installing and uninstalling Python from Microsoft Store.

Go to Microsoft WindowApps directory, then delete ***python.exe*** and ***python3.exe***

```
cd C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps 
del python.exe 
del python3.exe
```